# New version of LibreOffice file reverts back to previous version

Tags: libreoffice

I worked on a file in LibreOffice. I saved it as a .docx file. Let's call this version 1 of the file. Later today, I opened the file, made very important changes over the course of several hours, and saved the file. Let's call this version 2 of the file. All this took place in LibreOffice, on the same computer, with nothing weird happening (as far as I can tell).

Now that I open the file again, what I am presented being presented by LibreOffice is version 1, and not version 2. All the changes I made are lost. This is very very problematic for me, and I have no idea how this could happen. I have heard of compatibility issues with docx files and issues with formatting, but not of a complete version disappearing.

The hard drive has shown no problems and all other things seem to be in order. It's just this file. Is this a LO issue? Or an Ubuntu issue? This folder is tracked in Dropbox... are there any bugs with that software that can cause this? And, absolutely most important: are there any ways I can recover version 2 of the file?!

Comment: Make sure that the version 2 was not saved in LibreOffice's native ODF format. If so, open that file and save as docx.

Comment: I think the solution to your problem can be found here.  (https://www.farbeyondcode.com/Workaround-for-bug-in-LibreOffice-Writer-when-text-is-lost-after-saving-and-reopening-docx-files-5-3054.html) although I don't know if it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox is a flag for me. At work my team uses a Dropbox share for project files, and if the same file is opened by two users at once, changes will be made to a cloned file not the main instance of the file. Check that you don't have a second similarly named file in Dropbox which contains your changes.

Comment: I definitely agree. The first thing to do is to go on the Dropbox website and look for deleted files and older versions of the same files. It is also to be noted that a problem with timestamps might occur, that might result in overwriting the version "2" with a previous one.

Comment: Note that dropbox is only used for backup-purposes. It is only used on one machine. No one else opens the file at the same time. Would this then still apply?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you saved it where you think you saved it? I found a few copies I didn't expect in my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are working with versions of a document in two separated files**:

1.Open the copy of the document,
2.Go to menu Edit > Compare document,
3.Select the original of the document and click the button Insert

**LibreOffice will combine both documents:**

1.the text in common is shown normally;

2.the passages of text which are displayed in the copy of your document, but not in the original, are identified as insertions;

3.the missing passages of text in the copy of your document in comparison with the original are identified as removals.